# How to write xpath for below screenshot

Tags: appium

I am new in appium. I want to find element for username and password displayed in screenshot. If i am using //class then value is same for both username and password. Please help. I want to know all methods to identify the elements(like using class, id, xpath) if possible.

Thanks in advance. Please find the screenshot below

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWqHK.png)

Comment: according to the screenshot, your resource-id is `null` so you cannot use `ById` locator strategy, class name for both the elements is `android.widget.EditText` hence `ByClass` would not help you differentiate them unless you create a `List<WebElement>` and access them by index, so its better to use `ByXPath` in this case as explained by Gaurav in his answer since xpath would always be unique for an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Username - `driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText' and @index='0']");`

Password - `driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText' and @index='1']");`

Comment: I think in this case both the `EditText` are indexed `0`, their parent `View` are indexed uniquely(3,4). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes exactly.Both the EditText are indexed as 0. Tell me how i will use the parent index or is there any other way to write the xpath. I have tried using bound values also, but i think that values changes when using in different different devices.I have added image for password field also.Please find the screenshot attached above

Comment: Akash, did you try above mentioned code and it doesn't work?